# css scroll snapping sections in fixed navbar

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed nav bar with 3 sections. whenever i scroll, the sections should be under the nav bar with a margin of 10px. I have applied the following code, but its not working as expected. attached image for reference

Consider this as structure

```html
<body>
<nav style="position:fixed;margin-bottom:10px" >flex-nav items</nav>
<main>
<div class=section> some list contents<div>
<div class=section> some list contents<div>
<div class=section> some list contents<div>
</main>
<body>
```

css

```css
main {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.section {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

Expected:

**Main page**
[image: Main page]

**Second page**
[image: Second page]

Actual:

[image: 3]

Answer (score 0):

When you add `position: fixed` to your navbar, the `main` will not consider the navbar's height while placing itself.

So you can add a `calc()` for the margin which adds your navbar's height to the margin.

eg.

*If the navbar's height is 50px*

```
margin-top: calc(50px + 10px)
```

Comment: added this in main, it is adding margin for the whole page and moving the navbar down

Comment: ohh my bad it should be `margin-top: calc(50px + 10px)`

Comment: it is adding margin, i donno why navbar is moving down according to margin.

Comment: can u add the whole code please it will help to debug the code

Comment: try adding `top: 0; left: 0` to navbar

Comment: not working, i see double scroll bar in desktop view

Comment: can u share the screenshot?